# Determine number of char movement to get word

Tags: string, algorithm

Suppose you are given a word

"sunflower"

You can perform only one operation type on it, pick a character and move it to the front.
So for instance if you picked 'f', the word would be "fsunlower".

You can have a series of these operations.

1. fsunlower (moved f to front)
2. wfsunloer (moved w to front)
3. fwsunloer (moved f to front again)

The problem is to get the minimum number of operations required, given the derived word and the original word. So if input strings are "fwsunloer", "sunflower", the output would be 3.

Comment: If the output is 3, by "brute force" you would only need to test 9*9*9 combinations. Even if there is no answer, one would need to check "only" 9^9 combinations.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is equivalent to : given String A and B, find the **longest suffix** of string A that is a [**sub-sequence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of String B. Because, if we know which n - characters need to be moved, we will only need n steps. So what we need to find is the maximum number of character that don't need to be moved, which is equivalent to the longest suffix in A.

So for the given example, the longest suffix is `sunlor`

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(minOp("ewfsunlor", "sunflower"));
}

public static int minOp(String A, String B) {
    int n = A.length() - 1;//Start from the end of String A;
    int pos = B.length();
    int result = 0;
    while (n >= 0) {
        int nxt = -1;
        for (int i = pos - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (B.charAt(i) == A.charAt(n)) {
                nxt = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nxt == -1) {
            break;
        }
        result++;
        pos = nxt;
        n--;
    }
    return B.length() - result;
}
```

Result:

```
3
```

Time complexity O(n) with n is length of String A.

**Note**: this algorithm is based on an assumption that A and B contains same set of character. Otherwise, you need to check for that before using the function